# How to update properties with Hibernate Panache?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have the following DDL definition:

```
@Entity
data class Interest(
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "interests")
    var account: List<Account> = listOf(),
    var description: String = "") : PanacheEntity()


@Entity
data class Account(@field:Id var uuid: UUID? = null,
                   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) var gender: Gender? = null,
                   var birthday: Long = 0,
                   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
                   @JoinTable(
                       name = "account_interests",
                       joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "account_id")],
                       inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "interest_id")]
                   )
                   var interests: List<Interest> = listOf()) : PanacheEntityBase
```

As you can see on the definition, I use **HIBERNATE ORM WITH PANACHE** and it follows Active Record pattern.
In addition, I have created `AccountRepository`:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class AccountRepository : PanacheRepository<Account> {

  @Transactional
  fun create(newAcc: Account): Account =
      persist(newAcc).let { newAcc }

  fun read(id: UUID): Account? =
      find("uuid", id).firstResult()

  @Transactional
  fun updateInterests(id: UUID, i: Interests): Int {
    println(i)
    return update("interests = ?1 where uuid = ?2", i, id)
  }

}
```

The problem that I have is the method `updateInterests`. It throws the exception:

```
RESTEASY002020: Unhandled asynchronous exception, sending back 500: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Interest(account=[], description=Luxury)] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
```

The incoming `interests` payload is:

```
[Interest(account=[], description=Luxury), Interest(account=[], description=Travel)]
```

How to update the property of the Account `interests` correctly?